# CSS problem, auto correct width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following code.. http://jsfiddle.net/L593G/7/ what would I need to add to make the query box auto resize depending on the menu? So as to prevent the text (when it's long) disappearing under the menu? To see what I mean type a long sentence into the query box and it'll vanish behind the menu. I'd prefer if it just cut off the text on the far left rather than the "new" additions getting hidden.

Comment: Why can't you just limit the width of the textbox, so that it doesn't go behind the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a *very* quick mock-up](http://jsfiddle.net/sdleihssirhc/LcmDQ/) of what I think you're trying to accomplish. Instead of actually placing the `select` inside the textbox, you can place both objects in a `div`, "hide" the textbox, and make the `div` look like a textbox.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2jtsm/

What I did was:

1. Instead of absolute positioning on menu, float it to the right
2. Place the input box inside another div, set `margin-right` of div to 100px
3. Gave a fixed width to menu select box

**Update:**

If you can have a fixed width on the box, here's a quick CSS trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/abnZ3/

Comment: I still want the effect of the menu being 'inside' the box.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with tables:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%"> 
            <input type="text" style="width: 100%"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
               <option value=1>a value</option>
               <option value=2>another value</option>
               <option value=3>and this is the final value</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>            
</table>
```